# how to solve JavaScript number in a series embedded in a HTML document

Tags: javascript

A code embedded in a HTML document that prompts user to enter a number.
The code then displays the next 3 numbers in the series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your question is not too clear, but i think i got it. You should try this;

```js
let num;
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {num = prompt('please enter a number')
      document.getElementById('nums').innerHTML = ``;
  for(let i = parseInt(num); i < parseInt(num) + 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById('nums').innerHTML += `${i},`;
  }
})
```

```html
    <p id='nums'></p>
    <button id='btn'>Click here</button>
```